# Output of "kubectl cluster-info" command

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Below is the output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:32772
KubeDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:32772/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I am using Minikube to run a single Node cluster in my local box to lean Kubernetes. I Google'ed Minikube docs and what I understood was that Minikube will launch a VM (in my case I used Oracle VirtualBox) in my local and runs a single Node Kubernetes cluster in the VM.

In the above output, "Kubernetes master is running at [https://127.0.0.1:32772"](https://127.0.0.1:32772%22) means Kubernetes master is running on my local box or inside the VM launched by Minikube?

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried to see which service is running on this port and below is the output:

```
C:\Users>netstat -a -o -n | find "32772"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:32772        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8892

C:\Users>
```

And `8892` is running `com.backend.docker.exe`. I am more confused now that is Docker running my cluster, if not then why it is showing that `com.backend.docker.exe` is running on port "32772".

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are asking for? How minikube works on Windows machine when you are using VirtualBox? How did you create this minikube? Did you see [this article](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/tools/kubernetes-minikube/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both assumptions are correct.

It's running in a VM, a VM which is running in your PC and exposing the Kubernetes API so that you can access it with kubectl without needing to get into the VM.

Comment: ok, thank you for your inputs, I have updated my question, could you please check.

Comment: @pjj you're certainly not using Minikube then, you're using Docker Desktop which ships with kubernetes support built-in. Check with `kubectl config get-context` and if you indeed installed Minikube, you should have two configs: one for minikube and other for docker desktop (this one with an `*` meaning it's currently in use.). Either case, just remove minikube, it's not necessary for some time, as Docker Desktop on Windows and macOS provides a cluster already. Minikube is only for Linux (and even then, Kind is preferred).

Comment: CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         minikube   minikube   minikube   default